# Pass ViewBag content from child to parent client page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I have `ViewBag` that contain this type:

```
ViewBag.contacts = List<UserContact>
```

The UserContact is:

```
public class UserContact
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public List<string> emails { get; set; }


    public UserContact()
    {
        emails = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

At some point I  pass to the client page HTML block that contains `ViewBag` with the data above.

At some point I need to pass the data in `ViewBag`  to the parent page.

My question is there any way to pass a `ViewBag` to the parent page for usage in parent page or any other way to pass the content of the `ViewBag` for usage in parent page?

Comment: What do you mean by 'parent page'? Please talk in terms of Views, not Pages.

Comment: @AmateurProgrammer: My assumption would be "parent" contains `@RenderBody()`, and "child" is defining `ViewBag.contacts` and ends up as the contents of `@RenderBody()`.

Comment: The same way you define the ViewBag to pass it to the View, you must define again to pass it to your other View. What is exactly your issue?

Comment: To pass it up the calling chain you may want to use `TempData`. However, FWIW, you really should be looking at a better way to pass this kind of information. Moreover, the ViewBag should be used sparingly with a favoritism towards defined models. Maybe define the original problem at hand and not how to accomplish your work-around?

Comment: Brad what do you mean "by way pass this kind of information"?Any suggestions?

Comment: Passing models in view bag properties is bad practice. Pass you model or a view model to the view instead.